# MySQL server overloading

Tags: mysql, server, connection

I have a MySQL server that is hosting my website. Yesterday, after trying to empty a certain database, I started receiving the following error when attempting to connect to my site :

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections in lock_may_be_available() 
>   (line 167 of /home/vksappc/public_html/prod/includes/lock.inc).

After searching online for a possible solution, I restarted the server and everything was okay. Today, however, I've noticed that the number of active connections is constantly and slowly rising until it reaches the limit of 151 :

[Screenshot of thread count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6BY3.png)

[image]

At which point the server then seems to timeout those connections and everything resets, only to start its gradual climb all over again:

[Screenshot of new thread count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZK6g.png)

[image]

This is really becoming a big problem and as I am quite new to managing a server, I am not too sure what could be causing this or what to do next.

Any ideas?

Comment: If sounds like your CONNECTIONS are not being closed, when user is finished. Post your 'CONNECT', process, thru CLOSE() code as well as additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: Please also post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%threa%';

Comment: Hi @WilsonHauck, thanks for the comments. It was indeed a specific connection that was not being closed and just running again and again in a loop. We were able to see which one it was and shut it down, thanks to your thought process. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Phil, Anytime.  Could I get an upvote or two?  Would still provide suggestions for improvement if data requested 8/22/19 could be posted.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I will definitely upvote your comment...as soon as I reach the required 15 rep

Comment: Thanks for your upvotes.   Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links. Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for server WORKLOAD tuning analysis and helpful performance enhancing suggestions will be posted.

Comment: To be honest Wilson, as I said in my post, I am quite new at this and don't really know where to get all that information

Comment: If you have Skype TALK access (there are no fees to Canada), and allowed to Share Screen with me and 15 minutes of time, I will guide you in gathering this information.  Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile for FREE Utility Script downloads and contact information.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a specific connection that was stuck in a loop of sending a request unsuccessfully and trying over and over again. Once we found which connection it was, we were able to kill all its processes and fix the issue. Thanks to @WilsonHauck for the tip in the comments.